# Deserialising an object containing timestamps

Tags: java, mysql

We have a scenario where a user uploads database data. The user reads the data from the database onto java objects and then serialises the java objects into a file. This file is then uploaded to a remote server. On the remote server, I then deserialise this file and put it onto a database on the remote server.

The problem appears when I deserialise timestamps and dates. The timestamps were different when compared to the one on the client system. We traced the problem back to an incorrectly set timezone on the client system. The client was on a Pacific Time US and Canada(UTC - 8:00) and the server was on Indian Time (UTC + 5:30). Hence when the database inserted the data it compensated for the time difference. We changed the incorrectly set timezone on the client system and everything is now fine.

But we dont have control on all the client systems. If they are on a different timezone (set on their system incorrectly) then how do we instruct the server not compensate and store the data as is. Meaning the deserialising should put the data in the DB exactly as sent by the user.

Also, if we move our server to a different timezone, the problem will manifest for all users then.

We use java and the database is mysql

EDIT: Here's a code sample:

```
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DBObject db = new DBObject();
        db.setTs(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

     //first save the data on one timezone
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/Sethu/temp/test.dat"));
        os.writeObject(db);
        os.close();

     //comment the top portion of saving.. change the timezone and run the code, 
     //you will see a different date appearing in your screen   
        ObjectInputStream is=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("/Users/Sethu/temp/test.dat"));
        DBObject dbin=(DBObject)is.readObject();
        System.out.println(dbin.getTs());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
    }

   class DBObject implements Serializable{
   private Timestamp ts;

   public Timestamp getTs() {
    return ts;
   }

   public void setTs(Timestamp ts) {
    this.ts = ts;
   }

  }
```

Edit 2: In order to convert the date back into the Timezone where it was originally created, I have now change the code to send the Timezone serialised as well. Now the timezone is first serialised object and the DBObject is second one.. Now using the serialised timezone I am trying to change the resonctructed object:

```
System.out.println("Current Timezone="+DateTimeZone.getDefault());
DateTimeZone timezone=(DateTimeZone)is.readObject();
System.out.println("Timezone of saved object="+timezone);
DBObject dbin=(DBObject)is.readObject();
System.out.println("Date in current timezone="+dbin.getTs());

System.out.println("Date time Object in timezone of saved object="+new    DateTime(dbin.getTs()).withZone(timezone));

//This is where the issue is.. As soon as I do this, I get the date in the current timezone again..
System.out.println("Date time exported to date="+new DateTime(dbin.getTs()).withZone(timezone).toDate());
```

When I do this, this is the output I am getting!

```
Current Timezone=America/Los_Angeles
Timezone of saved object=+05:30
Date in current timezone=Tue Dec 06 23:30:56 PST 2011
Date time Object in timezone of saved object=2011-12-07T13:00:56.687+05:30
Date time exported to date=Tue Dec 06 23:30:56 PST 2011
```

Comment: It's not clear whether the problem is in the serialization or the database, and you haven't given us any code or any indication of the types involved. That makes it very hard to give an answer.

Comment: Just a guess: save date as milliseconds (type Long)?

Answer (score 1):

I would store all timestamps as GMT on the server and the client. I only change it to the user's preferred time zone when displaying the time. This avoid confusion over which time zone was used to store or retrieve the date/time and was it correct etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add timezone information on your `DBObject` as well since the `TimeZone` class is serializable. To get the current TimeZone, just use `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone()`.

Comment: I did try that. I added the timezone as another field and obtained the same on the server. But how do I apply it to the deserialised timestamp? I am struggling with that. Could you help me by editing your answer and post a small code snippet please?